# Restore changes pushed while in detached HEAD

Tags: git

I have on my git 2 branches, master and SSL.
While I thought I was on master branch, I was actually detached. I pushed the changes to HEAD, then checkout to SSL branch and merged it.
When I did that, I found out that the changes committed to the master were no present on any branch and I couldn't see them.
Is there a way to restore the lost commits?

Running `git reflog -n 20`:

```
 e4a206b HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from SSL to master
94e0f8d HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to SSL
e4a206b HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from SSL to master
94e0f8d HEAD@{3}: reset: moving to 94e0f8d
18aedb9 HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to SSL
e4a206b HEAD@{5}: checkout: moving from e4a206b20456d004b5ad19bb859e15f481df9b90 to master
e4a206b HEAD@{6}: checkout: moving from SSL to master^0
18aedb9 HEAD@{7}: checkout: moving from master to SSL
e4a206b HEAD@{8}: checkout: moving from e4a206b20456d004b5ad19bb859e15f481df9b90 to master
e4a206b HEAD@{9}: checkout: moving from master to master^0
e4a206b HEAD@{10}: checkout: moving from d8b6feee2ae2595872d62ca2b25c01263b3bf74b to master
d8b6fee HEAD@{11}: merge SSL: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
94e0f8d HEAD@{12}: commit: Support for os and badge count for ios
e4a206b HEAD@{13}: checkout: moving from 18aedb908898083d8b9d6941ec59f981950a3846 to master^0
18aedb9 HEAD@{14}: checkout: moving from bc071caacff35fca304aae97804fd9070d92913f to SSL^0
bc071ca HEAD@{15}: commit: Added support for sell option
e4a206b HEAD@{16}: checkout: moving from 18aedb908898083d8b9d6941ec59f981950a3846 to master^0
18aedb9 HEAD@{17}: checkout: moving from e4a206b20456d004b5ad19bb859e15f481df9b90 to SSL^0
e4a206b HEAD@{18}: checkout: moving from SSL to master^0
18aedb9 HEAD@{19}: commit: SSL
```

I have done a hard reset to the commit I wanted, It is still missing a file (I really don't know how).

Comment: When you say "gone", the changes you want aren't present on master but they are present on your other branch?

Comment: Please describe what "gone" means here. If you actually committed the changes to the master branch, it's very hard to lose those changes. Did you do a `git reset` ? Have you tried checking out master?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Use `git reflog`.

Comment: Would you mind adding your reflog to the question? Just run `git reflog -n 10` (replace 10 with whatever number of commits include the issue). Thanks.

Comment: Run `git log` with each recent reflog commit and find the commits you want. Check out `master` and then cherry-pick them one by one to `master`.

Comment: Try `git checkout HEAD@{4}`. This will checkout the repo before you reset and you should see your lost work. You can then commit the work as you normally would.

Comment: @brntsllvn thank you, I got back to the point where I have had to most data saved. Unfortunately I didn't commit all my changes, but at least most of it is back!

Comment: Ah bummer...yep we can only git back what the repo knows about. Reset is incredibly destructive. I'll type up an answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on `git reflog`, it looks like you ran `git reset` at `94e0f8d HEAD@{3}`.

You should be able to recover any **committed** work by simply checking out the commit before the reset: `git checkout HEAD@{4}`

One last thought: when you receive a "detached HEAD" notification, run `git status` for some useful guidance:

> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make
>   experimental changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits
>   you make in this state without impacting any branches by performing
>   another checkout.
>
> **If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you
>   may do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again.**
>   Example:
>
> git checkout -b new-branch-name
>
> HEAD is now at 81f96ab... some commit msg

Comment: That's what I did. Thanks.